# Choosing a cluster with low variance and many data points

Tags: clustering, variance, optimization

I have data points that have been grouped using k-means clustering. Some of these clusters may only have one data point, which would give them a variance of zero. But I am more interested in the clusters that still have a low variance, but many data points. I need to somehow choose the cluster that strikes a good balance between the two. Is there a statistical concept that can be used for this?